# Related to sequence of function

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eIfx.jpg)

I've done the options B, C, Dand B is uniformly convergent. But what about option A, I am unable to check weather it's convergence uniform or not?? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1-|x|)^{n} \to 0$ pointwise. But $(1-\frac  1{n^{2}})^{n}=((1-\frac  1{n^{2}})^{n^{2}})^{\frac n {n^{2}}} \to (\frac 1 e)^{0}=1$. Hence the convergence is not uniform.

Details: suppose the sequence converges uniformly. Let $0<\epsilon <1$. Since the pointwise limit is $0$ it follows that the uniform limit is also $0$. By definition, there exists $n_0$ such that $(1-|x|)^{n}<\epsilon$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$ for all $n \geq n_0$. In particular $(1-\frac 1 {n^{2}})^{n}<\epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$. Letting $n \to \infty$ we get $1 \leq \epsilon$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Sir i understood the pointwise convergence. But what you did in 2nd step,  i didn't get it.  I know that if norm tends to 0 then sequence of function is uniformly convergent.  Please explain 2nd step. Thanks

Comment: @user684646 See my answer now.

Comment: Thank you sir. I got it.